# How to display my combobox value onto my report?

Tags: c#, winforms, parameters, combobox, reportviewer2008

I have a form with a combobox and datetimepicker. i want the user to select a value from the combobox and choose a date and this value needs to be captured as a parameter and display on the report where the date equals chosen date and itempiececode equals chosen combobox value.

The Pieces Involved

The Form - Piece Code.cs
The Report - Report6.rdlc
The ReportViewer on the Form Piece Code.cs - reportviewer1

If you still dont understand what my question is please click the -> [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ohCG.jpg)

the highlighted yellow is what i need.

The Code i have sooo far

**To fill the reportviewer**

```
private void PieceCode_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'CorsicanaNetWeightDataSet9.CandyPieceSize' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    this.CandyPieceSizeTableAdapter.Fill(this.CorsicanaNetWeightDataSet9.CandyPieceSize);
    // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'CorsicanaNetWeightDataSet4.PieceDimensionMasterDataUpdate' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    this.PieceDimensionMasterDataUpdateTableAdapter.Fill(this.CorsicanaNetWeightDataSet4.PieceDimensionMasterDataUpdate);
    // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'corsicanaNetWeightDataSet4piece.Item_Piece' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    this.item_PieceTableAdapter.Fill(this.corsicanaNetWeightDataSet4piece.Item_Piece);
    PieceReport pr = new PieceReport();
    reportViewer1.Visible = false;
    this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
}
```

**To Fill the Combobox i used datasource and displaymemeber property**
** I used the report wizard to generate report6**

**i used GUI for most of the program so not much code to share**

**Summary of what i need**
i need the combobox1.selectedtext set equal to a parameter on report6  and the datetimepicker.text = to another parameter so i can display it in my reportviewer?? or if there is any other workaround for the program.

**I am being completely honest here and please dont close this as off topic, or dock me down because i have provided everything i have for your understanding and please help me as this is the last part of my project and i would really love to complete it before the holidays and spend time with family thanks for all your help**

**Tried it with Code, GUI just does not cut it at times**

```
namespace CorsicanaNetWeightProgram
{
    public partial class PieceCode : Form
    {

        public string constr = "Data Source=KCMJF1XTR1\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CorsicanaNetWeight;Integrated Security=True";

        public reportfiller fullpiecedetails;

        public piecedescription piece;


        PieceReport pr = new PieceReport(); 
        public PieceCode()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void PieceCode_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'CorsicanaNetWeightDataSet9.CandyPieceSize' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.

            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'corsicanaNetWeightDataSet4piece.Item_Piece' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
           // this.item_PieceTableAdapter.Fill(this.corsicanaNetWeightDataSet4piece.Item_Piece);
            PieceReport pr = new PieceReport();
            reportViewer1.Visible = false;
            piece = new piecedescription();
            fillpiece();



            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        }

        private void fillpiece()
        {
            try
            {
            using(MSSQL.SqlConnection connection = new MSSQL.SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                connection.Open ();
                using (MSSQL.SqlCommand command = new MSSQL.SqlCommand("SELECT Item + '-' + Description AS PieceDescription FROM dbo.[Piece Dimension Master Data]" ,connection))
                {
                  MSSQL.SqlDataAdapter myadapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter();
                        myadapter.SelectCommand = command;
                        myadapter.Fill(piece, "DataTable1");
                comboBox1.DataSource = piece.DataTable1;
                comboBox1.ValueMember = "PieceDescription";
                comboBox1.DisplayMember = "PieceDescription";


        }
            }
            }

            catch (Exception) { /*Handle error*/ }
            }


        private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {          

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 


            reportViewer1.Visible = true;
            {
                using (MSSQL.SqlConnection connection = new MSSQL.SqlConnection(constr))
                {
                    fullpiecedetails = new reportfiller();
                    connection.Open();
                    //MSSQL.SqlCommand command = new MSSQL.SqlCommand("SELECT * From EtimePunchDetail WHERE (EmpID = @empid) And  (Paygroup = @paygroup) And (TransDate >= @fromdate) And (TransDate <= @todate)", connection);
                    MSSQL.SqlCommand command = new MSSQL.SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.[Piece Dimension Master Data] WHERE Item + '-' + Description  = @piecedesc", connection);
                    {

                        MSSQL.SqlParameter parmEmp = new MSSQL.SqlParameter();
                        parmEmp.ParameterName = "@piecedesc";
                        parmEmp.Value = comboBox1.SelectedValue;
                        command.Parameters.Add(parmEmp);



                        MSSQL.SqlDataAdapter EtimePunchDetailTableAdapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter();
                        EtimePunchDetailTableAdapter.SelectCommand = command;
                        EtimePunchDetailTableAdapter.Fill(fullpiecedetails, "DataTable1");



                        string exeFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
                        string reportPath = exeFolder + @"\Report6.rdlc";



                        reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = reportPath;

                        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

                        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("reportfiller_DataTable1", fullpiecedetails));
                        reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
                        reportViewer1.Refresh();
                        reportViewer1.Visible = true;
                   }
                }
            }

        }
```

**I am getting the following error "Value does not fall within the expected range." At this part of the code  reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("reportfiller_DataTable1", fullpiecedetails));**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new form, added a fresh report, new data set and did everything through the GUI - Used the wizard to generate the report.

I edited the data set to the following code

```
SELECT Item, Description, [Piece Category], Shape, [Deposit Weight], [Center Weight], [Center Weight Constant], [Coating Weight], [Coating Weight Constant], [Decorations Weight], [Inclusions Weight], [Center Diameter_LL], [Center Diameter_UL], [Center Length_LL], [Center Length_UL], [Center Width_LL], [Center Width_UL], [Center Height_LL], [Center Height_UL], [Center Weight Variation], [Coated Diameter_LL], [Coated Diameter_UL], [Coated Length_LL], [Coated Length_UL], [Coated Width_LL], [Coated Width_UL], [Coated Height_LL], [Coated Height_UL], [Coated Weight Variation], Item + '-' + Description AS [PieceDescription] FROM [Piece Dimension Master Data] WHERE **Item + '-' + Description  = @piece**
```

Then added a table to the report with all required columns

**The GUI Had Generated this code for me**

```
namespace CorsicanaNetWeightProgram
{
    public partial class PieceCodepc : Form
    {
        public PieceCodepc()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void PieceCodepc_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'dataSet1.DataTable1' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.dataTable1TableAdapter.Fill(this.dataSet1.DataTable1);

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'empty.Piece_Dimension_Master_Data' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.Piece_Dimension_Master_DataTableAdapter.Fill(this.empty.Piece_Dimension_Master_Data, comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());

            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();


        }
    }
}
```

**All i did was pass comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString() to DataTableAdapter and IT WORKED!!!!!**

Answer (score 1):

Say your parameter name for date is DateParameter. To set the value I'll do the following:

```
        ReportParameter rpDateParameter = new ReportParameter();
        rpDateParameter.Name = "DateParameter";
        rpDateParameter.Values.Add(dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString());
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { rpDateParameter });

        // Refresh the report
        reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Comment: I tried something similar to your code but i am getting "the value does not fall within the expected range error." I added my code in my question please take a look at that for reference.